# ASP.NET Windows Authentication not working in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, authentication

So I have a ASP.NET site that use Windows Authenication that only does one thing:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        somelabel.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
        return;
    }
```

Unfortunately it is always false for some reason.  Here is my web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I deployed it on my Windows 7 running IIS 7.5.

- Windows Authentication is installed and enabled
- Target framework is 4.0
- Application pool pipeline thing is integrated
- Extended protection in Windows Authentication is "off" and "accept" (tried both)

Answer (score 3):

Change the authorization section to:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I think that by saying `allow users="*"` you are allowing every body access.

See this post by [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)

Comment: You mean deny users="?". What you've written would allow anonymous users only

Comment: @simonhalsey I meant to copy that section of the web.config from Scott's blog but obviously didn't do it right. It's corrected now, thanks a lot!